# How to install vcredist.exe files from Wix Setup Bootstrap Project

Tags: wix

I am trying to install the Visual C++ Redistributables along with the .msi for my application. However when I go to install the project I keep getting a "Another install is currently running error". Here is my bundle.wxs file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Bundle Name="Application" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" UpgradeCode="6c5daa41-4ce9-4f20-94b2-2471a6932542">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
        <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
        <PackageGroupRef Id="MyPackage" />
        <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile=".\Application.msi"/>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
<Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="MyPackage">
        <ExePackage Id="VisualCPlusPlus32Bit"
              DisplayName="Microsoft Visual C++"
              SourceFile=".\vcredist_x86.exe"
              Vital="no"
              InstallCommand="/q /ACTION=Install"
              DetectCondition="NOT VersionNT64"/>
        <ExePackage Id="VisualCPlusPlus64Bit"
              DisplayName="Microsoft Visual C++"
              SourceFile=".\vcredist_x64.exe"
              Vital="no"
              InstallCommand="/q /ACTION=Install"
              DetectCondition="VersionNT64"/>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I have looked at the docs for wix and this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/installing-prerequisites-using-wix-bootstrapper-project-and/) but I still cant get the Visual C++ libraries installed first without two installs run concurrently.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure those are the right commands to run your installations? I have several versions of vcredist with different install commands (thanks MS) like "/install /quiet /norestart", "/Q /C:&quot;msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn&quot;", "/quiet". You can also take a look at the log file created in %temp% when running your bootstrapper, see which package it fails on.

Comment: @BrianSutherland It seems that the install is being called correctly as the Visual C++ install window pops up. But that only pops up after the install screen of my application. Seems like the vcredist.exe isnt being finished before my .msi runs.

Comment: I might have had this problem with one of the vcredist packages at one point. What happens is the exe actually unpacks and launches another program then exits while the other program continues (the real install) the bootstrapper thinks the install completed since the launched program exits with 0 and continues installing other packages. You should be able to test with running the installs from cmd line. You can install vcredist over and over so don't worry about running it more than once for testing.

Comment: I think I just had to mess around with calling the exe with /? /help to try to get a help for commands then I could use a command to unpack it to a directory. To my surprise it unpacked another vcredist.exe, using this one in the bootstrapper worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How To: Install the Visual C++ Redistributable with your installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html). This approach uses a Merge Module to include the Visual C++ Redistributables with your msi instead of running vcredist as a separate installer.

Comment: This lead me in the right direction. I was able to get [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-to-an-application-local-folder) solution to work for me. Thanks!

Comment: The link mentioned above does not work. Here is a working link:  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-to-an-application-local-folder?view=vs-2019

Comment: following that link is ok but then I cannot find where does the MSI installs the redist files out of merge module on the target machine???

Comment: Microsoft deprecated merge modules